# Debug Visual Studio 2005 Web Service from Visual Studio 2008 Client

Tags: .net, web-services, debugging

I have a .NET Web Service running in VS2005 and a client that consumes it running in VS2008. Is there any way, while debugging the client, I can step into the code of the service? Both are running locally.

Many thanks for your time,

P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both projects are configured to start on debug, I think it will step into the service code.

Though you might need to set check the  "Don't open a page" radiobutton in the service project  propertypages startOptions.

Answer (score 2):

VS 2008 can debug code built with VS 2005. You can attach to the web service process and debug it as any other process. Note that you might have to start second instance of Visual Studio, since attaching to existing process will stop your current debugging session.